# Terraform external data in metadata_startup_script

Tags: terraform, kube-proxy

I'm going to parsing a token value from other .tf file into other .tf file

I have tried to understand this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262234/how-to-use-external-data-source-in-terraform-with-bash-script)  and also from this [article](https://medium.com/@jmarhee/using-external-data-sources-with-terraform-c3de27388192)

**data.tf**

```
data "external" "get_token" {
  program = ["/bin/sh", "${path.module}/get-token.sh"]
}
```

**get-token.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
token=$(kubectl -n kube-system exec [POD_NAME] cat /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig 2>/dev/null | grep token | awk '{print $2}'
```

**proxy.tf**

```
...
metadata_startup_script = <<-EOT
- name: kube-proxy
  user:
    token: ${lookup(data.external.get_token.result, "token")}
    certificate-authority-data: ${google_container_cluster.new_container_cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate}
...
EOT
```

My expectation is 
`token` has the value as same as with `certificate-authority-data`.
`certificate-authority-data` has a exact value like i expect but the `token` is nil or blank.
I have run my `get-token.sh` manually and it's good. But when terraform want to parse it, the value is not parsed successfully. I have added `'` before and after the variable `${lookup(data.external.get_token.result, "token")}`. Seems not to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

> The program must then produce a valid JSON object on stdout, which
>   will be used to populate the result attribute exported to the rest of
>   the Terraform configuration. This JSON object must again have all of
>   its values as strings. On successful completion it must exit with
>   status zero.

So the script should return a json object.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
# add below line for make a json result
jq -n --arg token "$token" '{"token":$token}'
```

or if there is no jq,

```
#!/bin/bash
...
#add below
echo -n "{\"token\":\"${token}\"}"
```