# Terraform :: how to use WHOAMI as a tag

Tags: git, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file, whoami

We are using Terraform to manage our infrastructure.

One of the tags that we use is called **updatedBy** and it's supposed to show the e-mail of the person that updated that resource:

```
  tags = {
    "updatedBY" = "name.surname@contoso.com"
  }
```

As you can imagine so many times people input the wrong e-mail.

Is there a way I can put that e-mail in a variable using:

- `WHOAMI`: for Linux users
- [whoami /upn](https://superuser.com/questions/836220/get-email-address-of-current-logged-in-user/1347697#1347697): for Windows users
- `git config user.email`: for both

In my opinion `git config user.email` should be the way to go because it's OS agnostic and all our Terraform engineers use Git.

But how to put that [into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041699/how-to-use-bash-commands-in-terraform-template-file-variables) so they cannot be wrong again?

Comment: Use a data external program that runs `git config user.email` ?

Comment: @Paolo comment-->answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the OP provided a link to another answer which does illustrate how to use a data external program.. so I was waiting for confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AzureRM Client Config](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/client_config) provider and the [AADUser](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/user) provider to update with the Deploying Users UPN

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_user" "current_user" {
  object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = var.resourceGroupName
  location = var.location
  tags = {
    "updatedBY" = data.azuread_user.current_user.user_principal_name
  }
}
```